# Jersey Method not allowed 405

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to the rest services. I am trying to create a service that accepts json string from a client.  I am getting 405 error when I am calling this service using JQuery.
Below is the Java code for ws:

```
@POST
@Path("logevent")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean logEvent(String obj)
{
  System.out.println(obj);
  return true;
}
```

and

```
@Path("getdata")
@GET
public String getData()
{
  return "Hello";
}
```

and jQuery code for posting the JSON is:

```
var json ="{\"userName\":\"testtest\"}";
var json_data =  JSON.stringify(json);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/log/log/logevent",
    // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
     data: json_data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
```

What is going wrong? The post is not working, however when I hit the get using the URL `http://<serverip>/log/log/getdata` I get the response.

Comment: Thanks Michal for correcting the typo.

Comment: What is the `@Path` of the class? Does JAX-RS match `/log/log/logevent` to the method `logEvent()`?

Comment: Do you mean that it *does* match?

Comment: You use `http://localhost:8080/` in jQuery, `<serverip>` in the browser. Are both the same?

Comment: I am using http://localhost:8080/log/log/logevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON `MessageBodyReader`s are able to unmarshal JSON stream into a JAXB bean (or POJO) but not into a String. Create a JAXB bean like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(final String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

and change your `POST` resource method to:

```
@POST
@Path("logevent")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean logEvent(User obj) {}
```

Comment: Then change `@Consumes` from `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` and also `contentType` in your ajax request to `text/plain`. But you'll have the `{"userName":"testtest"}` String in `obj`.

Comment: bingo...I am doing the same but it says can't consume content type

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that the path is `/log/log/logevent`

Then try changing the request/reponse type:

You should use `application/json;charset=UTF-8` (W3C XHR spec), moreover your webservice doesn't respond with JSON but ouptut a boolean, maybe you should change the response type.

For example with UTF-8:

**JAX-RS**

```
@Consumes("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

**jQuery**

```
contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, But this doesn't not work. I had tried thisbut got the same error.

Comment: Interesting thing is that I have a get method which works fine: @Path("getdata")
 @GET
 public String getData()
 {
  return "Hello";
 }