# HTTP Status 405 - Request 'POST' Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0

The problem is when i try to call api with @POST notation, i have this error:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request  'POST' Method Not Allowed
```

The other API (@GET) works.

The web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>uJerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs;com.info.smarti.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    </servlet>
   <!-- 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>uJerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->


      <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/UsersDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

UPDATE: I try to configure Tomcat with:

```
 <init-param>
            <param-name>readonly</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

but still not work..so the problem is maybe Jersey config..

Example API (POST):

```
 @Path("/cPass")
    @POST
    @ManagedAsync
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void cPassw(@QueryParam("token") String token,
            @QueryParam("categ") String category,
            @QueryParam("newpass") String newPassword,
            @Suspended final AsyncResponse response) throws Exception {
                       ....
       }
```

Comment: Ca you show the controller class?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147772/jersey-method-not-allowed-405) ?

Comment: yes i see but not work for me

Comment: @Jens what class so mean?

Comment: is there a POST method exposed as part of your API ?

Comment: Does PUT or DELETE work?

Comment: @FrAn i don't try PUT or DELETE..but i can do that if need

Comment: Might be good for debugging.

Comment: Are you sure that you are making the POST/PUT request to the correct URLs?

Comment: @FrAn yes of course, the error isn't 404 but 405

Comment: If you are trying to use url which accepts only GET with POST you get 405.
And you should define the servlet url mapping, now it is commented out. Try with this:

              `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>uJerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: i disable that because i use @ApplicationPath("path")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat, you have to enable PUT method at server.xml file

Look at http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html

Comment: Did you try to deploy your project into another AS such as Glassfish or Weblogic?

Comment: the problem was bad Jersey config

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi What was the problem with Jersey config? I had some similar problem..

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check the file which named endwith .java,and you must delete some sentences like "super.doGet(request, response); " or "super.doPost(request, response);" in your methods

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining why the OP’s problem occurs if those lines exist and how deleting them solves their problem?